# Does the water sight revelation require a focus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, oracle

If a 7th level Waves Oracle takes the Water Sight revelation, what spell components do they need to provide when using the scrying ability, if any?  My DM has ruled that I still need to provide a 1000g silver mirror as a focus, but I'm wondering if there is something we are both missing.

> Water Sight (Su): You can see through fog and mist without penalty as
> long as there is enough light to allow you to see normally. **At 7th
> level, you can use any calm pool of water at least 1 foot in diameter
> as a scrying device, as if using the scrying spell.** At 15th level,
> this functions like greater scrying. You can use the scrying abilities
> for a number of rounds per day equal to your oracle level, but these
> rounds do not need to be consecutive.
>
> Scrying Components
> Components V, S, M/DF (a pool of water), F (a silver mirror worth 1,000 gp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### [Components](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components) are usually a concern only when [casting a spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Casting-Spells)

An [oracle](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle) with the mystery [waves](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/waves) that picks the revelation water sight uses [*scrying*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying) as a [supernatural ability](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-) not a spell. Because such an oracle is *not* [casting a spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Casting-Spells) to use the revelation water sight for the effect of the spell *scrying*, the oracle does *not* employ [components](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Components), so the oracle needs only the calm at-least-1-ft.-diameter pool of water mandated by the revelation water sight rather than *two* pools of water, a 1,000-gp silver mirror, and a divine focus.

(On a somewhat more authoritative note, Paizo creative director James Jacobs says [in a 2010 thread](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2kilg?Wild-Shape-and-Supernatural-Abilities#2), "Supernatural abilities generally do not require things like components to function." And while that's slightly out of context, that *generally* should apply here, too.)

---

***Note:*** For detailed examinations of the scrying *spell's components, see answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131442/8610).*