# Wizard Scrying Spell Components - Do you need both a pool of water and a mirror, or just one?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spell-components

[Scrying](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying/) says:

> **Components** V, S, M/DF (a pool of water), F (a silver mirror worth 1,000 gp)

[The Magic rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Components) say that:

> If the Components line includes F/DF or M/DF, the arcane version of the spell has a focus component or a material component (the abbreviation before the slash) and the divine version has a divine focus component (the abbreviation after the slash).

I'm still confused because it has both a material and focus component.  As a wizard casting this spell, what exactly do I need?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As written, the required components for scrying are pretty confusing; read literally as-is, an arcane caster requires both a pool of water and a fancy mirror, whereas a divine caster requires a divine focus and a fancy mirror.

However, that almost certainly wasn't the intent; it looks like the description for *Scrying* suffered a little in the copying from 3.5e to Pathfinder. The [original 3.5e version](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/scrying.htm) is much more specific about the requirements the spell has:

> **Components:** V, S, M/DF, F
>
> ...
>
> *Arcane Material Component*
>
> The eye of a hawk, an eagle, or a roc, plus nitric acid, copper, and zinc.
>
> *Wizard, Sorcerer, or Bard Focus*
>
> A mirror of finely wrought and highly polished silver costing not less than 1,000 gp. The mirror must be at least 2 feet by 4 feet.
>
> *Cleric Focus*
>
> A holy water font costing not less than 100 gp.
>
> *Druid Focus*
>
> A natural pool of water.

This list is notably absent from the Pathfinder version, which is in keeping with Pathfinder's general trend of trying to simplify spell component requirements, though it seems that the intention was to retain a difference between the arcane and divine versions of the spell. It doesn't help that the 3.5 version of the spell was pretty unusual to begin with, as it specifies a unique divine focus (whereas the general rules for components say a divine focus is always an appropriate holy symbol or similar faith-related item), and thereby muddies the waters somewhat as to the definitions of things.

In my game, I would just refer to the components specified by the 3.5e version of the spell to make sense of *Scrying*. The arcane material component will almost never be important because of the ubiquitous spell component pouch anyway, so all you really need to worry about is the different focus that each version of the spell requires.

Alternatively, as HeyICanChan suggests, you could houserule the component description to read:

> **Components:** V, S, F (a silver mirror worth 1,000 gp)/DF

And then note in the text of the spell that a divine caster needs a pool of water in which to scry, as well as their normal divine focus; it's possible that this is closest to what was intended for Pathfinder's simplified version of the requirements.

Comment: It doesnt seem like its "missing", but simplified.

Comment: @ShadowKras I've reworded to "absent", to avoid implying a copy mistake - I agree they were probably trying to simplify, but didn't do a very good job in this instance.

Comment: @HeyICanChan are you basically saying that the entry should read F/DF rather than M/DF, F? (I don't disagree, it would make a lot more sense that way)

Comment: Sort of. It should say *V, S, F (a silver mirror worth 1,000 gp)/DF* then the text of the spell should say that a divine caster *also* needs a pool of water in addition to his "item of spiritual significance" to cast the spell. It's just that *Pathfinder*'s effort to simplify a spell's *Components* entry couldn't accommodate some of the more prop-heavy *3.5* spells so *Pathfinder* fakes it… and ends up with nonsense like with *scrying* that then confused later spell writers. (A DF is only supposed to be either a holy symbol or holly and mistletoe, for instance.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan FWIW a Divine Focus is described exactly the same way in the general rules for 3.5, but Scrying specifically overrules that with its own description of the divine focus - so the confusion starts before Pathfinder got to it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. I mean, the *scrying* spell is *complicated* in *3.5* but clear enough *according to itself* — the same can't be said about the *Pathfinder* version.

Comment: Upon reflection, I agree with ShadowKras's and your assessment that literally the spell's components require that everyone possess a special mirror but that arcanists also need to explode a pool of water and that divines also need to wave around their holy symbols or sacred shrubs. However, that still strikes me as an utterly bizarre divergence from *Pathfinder*'s source material. (Darn it, *Pathfinder*, why change *that* and leave untouched *freedom of movement*?)

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, you require both

As [Carcer pointed out in his answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131443/21153), the spell used to be a little more complicated back in 3.5, but Pathfinder simplified it. As explained on the Magic rules:

> **Material (M)**
>
> A material component consists of one or more physical substances or objects that are annihilated by the spell energies in the casting process. Unless a cost is given for a material component, the cost is negligible. Don’t bother to keep track of material components with negligible cost. **Assume you have all you need as long as you have your spell component pouch**.
>
> **If the Components line includes F/DF or M/DF**, the arcane version of the spell has a focus component or a material component (the abbreviation before the slash) and the divine version has a divine focus component (the abbreviation after the slash).

The proper way to read the components is that everything not explicitly mentioned as *"or"* is a requirement to cast the spell. The slash (/) means that its optional, arcane casters will use a material focus (M) and divine casters will use a divine focus (DF), but not both.

This separation will occur every time the spell appears both on arcane spell lists and divine spell lists. But if not mentioned as an optional component, it is as required as the *vocal* and *somatic* components of the spell. Of course, things like [Eschew Materials](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/eschew-materials-final/) will work for both type of spells, arcane or divine (and now psychic too).

But yes, even though it has a *negligible* cost, and can be assumed to be found inside your component pouch, you require both the *Material* and *Focus* components to cast the spell. And I can't seen to find *any* examples of a spell that requires either a *material* **or** *focus* component. It will either require both, or one of the two.

Also, keep in mind that **focuses are not consumed** when the spell is cast.

> **Focus (F)**
>
> A focus component is a prop of some sort. Unlike a material component, a focus **is not consumed** when the spell is cast and **can be reused**. As with material components, the cost for a focus is negligible unless a price is given. Assume that focus components of negligible cost are in your spell component pouch.

Comment: I think I'm almost on board, but to be clear: The spell requires an arcane caster to also annihilate a pool of water because *Pathfinder*'s revised components line couldn't handle requiring a divine caster to provide *both* a divine focus *and* a 1,000-gp mirror? (Because then the components line would be *V, S, DF, F* and that cannot be?) Is that accurate?

Comment: I don't know if that is raw, but it is surely how I will run that spell from now on.

Comment: @HeyICanChan if that was the intent, the "pool of water" part could be ignored entirelly, IMO. Divine casters use their divine focus (holy symbols) instead of whatever *no-cost* material component is listed for their spell. But let me ask you something, a *puddle* is considered a *pool* of water? A quick google translation tells me yes, but Id rather ask a native speaker.

Comment: That's kind of my point. From a story perspective, there's no reason for a wizard to have to annihilate an innocent pool (or puddle—synonyms? Sure, why not?) of water *and* stare into a special mirror to scry, yet there *is* a reason for a cleric to *invoke the gods with his holy symbol* and stare into a special mirror to scry! (The *3.5* joke was that for [*scying*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#scrying) a wizard needs 1,000-gp mirror, a cleric needs a 100-gp bowl, and a druid needs a full bladder. Druids rule!)

Comment: Im completely fine with a puddle being destroyed when the spell is cast, its a matter of flavoring the spell effect. For instance, in my mind right now, the caster captures the reflex of the stars (if its day, the spell makes it show the cosmos) in the location that his target is right now, and inserts it into the mirror, which will translate that into the location of the person he is trying to watch so he can look at them through the mirror.